# How to parallelize a nested loop with dask.distributed?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am trying to parallelize a nested loop using dask distribute that looks this way:

```
@dask.delayed
def delayed_a(e):
    a = do_something_with(e)
    return something

@dask.delayed
def delayed_b(element):
    computations = []
    for e in element:
        computations.add(delayed_a(e))

    b = dask.compute(*computations, scheduler='distributed',
                    num_workers=4)
    return b

list = [some thousands of elements here]
computations = []
for element in list:
    computations.append(delayed_b(element))
    results = dask.compute(*computations, scheduler='distributed',
                           num_workers=4)
```

As you see, I am using the `distributed` scheduler. First, I create a `computations` list with a lazy `delayed_b` function that takes as an argument one element from `list`. Then, `delayed_b` creates a new set of `computations` that are calling a `delayed_a` function and everything is executed in distributed. This pseudo code is working but I have found out that is faster if `delayed_a` is not there. Then my question is -- what would be the correct way of doing distributed parallel for loops?

At the end of the history what I am trying to do is:

```
list = [some thousands of elements here]
for element in list:
    for e in element:
        do_something_with(e)
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions about the best way of accomplishing doing nested loops with `dask.distributed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
something = dask.delayed(do_something_with_e
list = [some thousands of elements here]

# this could be written as a one-line comprehension
computations = []
for element in list:
    part = []
    computations.append(part)
    for e in element:
        part.append(something(e))

results = dask.compute(*computations, scheduler='distributed',
                       num_workers=4)
```

You should *never* be calling a delayed function or `compute()` within a delayed function.

(note that the distributed scheduler would be used by default, so long as you've created a Client)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test it today. You are right, I read yesterday the do's and don'ts when it comes to delayed functions. Is it possible to achieve the same you wrote about but when you use the `@delayed` decorator?

Comment: the call to `dask.delayed()` does the same thing as the decorator. If you can access the code for `do_something_with_e`, you can add the decorator. If you cannot, either do what is here, or write a decorated function as you had originally.

Comment: I think in your snippet above there is a `computations.append()` missing after looping over the `element` list. I found still that just passing the `element` list to a delayed function that does the `for e in element` is faster. Is that normal?  As you see, I am very new to both using dask and parallelizing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (edited - thanks) Whether or not is is faster depends on the size of the tasks and how well they parallelise. You can loop within the delayed function, but do not call delayed/compute there.

Comment: "You should never be calling a delayed function within a delayed function" -  Can you expand on this? Many of [the examples](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html) iteratively call delayed functions from one another

Comment: No they don't, they pass the results of calling delayed functions ("delayed objects") as the input to other delayed functions.